# Javascript Promise Scope Issue?

Tags: javascript, scope, promise

I think am having issue with the following, I was under the impression that this should return a string with 100 a's, followed by 100 b's, but when called with:

```
  const otherm = require("./testpromise.js")

console.log("calling promise now")

otherm.daycent_promise("me","lol").then(function(res,err){
  console.log(res);
  if(err!=null){
    console.log("there was an error"+err)
  }
})
```

from another file:

```
module.exports={
  daycent_promise: function (username,password){
    return somefunction(username,password)
  }
}


var somefunction = function(username, password){
  return new Promise(function(resolve,reject){
    if(username=="me"){
      var str = "";
      for(i=0;i<100; i++){
        str=str.concat("a")
      }
      for(x=0;x<100;x++){
        //console.log("testing")
        addgo(str)
        //str=str.concat("b");
      }
    }

resolve(str);
  })
}


function addgo(str){
  //console.log("testing")
str=str.concat("b");
  return str
}
```

But all I am getting is an output of 100 a's, even though addgo() is running. What is happening here?

Comment: This almost seems too easy, but what if you tried changing `addgo(str)` to `str = addgo(str)` ?

Comment: The problem is that `addgo` doesn't mutate the original string, but overwrites it locally.

Comment: Use `var str = "a".repeat(100);` instead of your first loop. You’re not assigning `str = addgo(str);`.

Answer (score 1):

Strings are passed by value. And you cant mutate strings, every modification creates a new string. So when you do:

```
addgo(str);//passes ""
console.log(str);//still "" never changed

function addgo(str){//own variable containing ""
 //console.log("testing")
 str=str.concat("b");//internal str is now "b"
  return str;//never used
}
```

Solution :

```
str=addgo(str);//str is overriden with "b"
```

By the way, much easier:

```
async function somefunction(username,password){
 return username==="me"?"a".repeat(100)+" b".repeat(100):undefined;
}
```

Comment: Thanks! That was a stupid mistake, assuming pass by ref. Its actually part of a much larger code that I am having difficulty with, which I will post below as I still cannot work out javascript scope and functions...:(

Comment: @gawnie JFYI : js has only pass by value for primitives or call by sharing for objects. And this question is answered, so please hit the green checkmark. If youve got another question, ask another one andd do not add it as an answer ( which it isnt)

Answer (score 1):

Replace str with the result coming from addgo

```
 for(x=0;x<100;x++){
    //console.log("testing")
   str=addgo(str)
    //str=str.concat("b");
  }
```